# ThreeJS Shader not rendering properly on OnePlus phones on Chrome

Tags: three.js, 3d, glsl, shader, webgl

i don't know if this is the right place to ask this, but i recently created [this](https://github.com/FarazzShaikh/glNoise) library.

[An issue](https://github.com/FarazzShaikh/glNoise/issues) bought to my attention that a OnePlus phone the vertex shader i use for displacing the vertices of a plane cuts off after a point.

[image]

This is not the case with my iPhone on iOS 14.5 though.

[image]

I have found that in the fBM function, at [these](https://github.com/FarazzShaikh/glNoise/blob/162049eeedfc590274118edc450beeea74fea5ab/src/Simplex.glsl#L76-L80) lines, setting the turbulence to true and taking the absolute value of the noise causes it to work but i do not want the turbulence to always be on.

Testing it on an other OnePlus phone seems to cause the issue, but testing it on a Samsung makes everything work perfectly

Any idea whats causing this bug?

Comment: If the issue is specifically with that turbulence variable, you can check if that variable is getting set properly from the client side.

Comment: @Atekihcan the turbulence variable is hardcoded before execution and is just a flag that when enabled takes the absolute value of the noise.